# How to return an value/null no matter the <index> column value is exist or not

Tags: sql, oracle

TABLES

```
<<USER>>
id     name
------------
1       alex
2       gary
3       peter
4       mary

<<ITEMS>>
id   index  items
-----------------
1      1    iphone
1      2    apple
2      1    nokia
```

SQL

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, i.items FROM USER u, ITEMS i
WHERE u.id = item.id(+)
AND (item.index = 2 OR item.index IS NULL);
```

Actual result

```
id     name    item
-----------------------
1      alex     apple
3      peter    <null>
4      mary     <null>
```

But my expected result is....

```
id     name    item
-----------------------
1      alex     apple
2      gary     <null>
3      peter    <null>
4      mary     <null>
```

I really don't know how to handle this part when index 2 is not found in id 2, I think it is the mainly root cause of returning this result without row of "gary".

Comment: Please stop using the proprietary `(+)` operator and use an explicit `left join` (even the Oracle manual recommends to do so)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a standard `LEFT JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, i.items
FROM USER u
    LEFT JOIN ITEMS i ON u.id = i.id
      AND i.index = 2 OR i.index IS NULL;
```

Note that the item's conditions are in the `ON` clause - to get a true outer join! (If they are in `WHERE`, it would execute as a regular inner join.)

Hmm, perhaps you can remove `OR i.index IS NULL` part...

Comment: wouldn't give the same result in case there is an item for id 2 where the index is null though right jarlh? if you removed the index is null, like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/30736/1

Comment: @JeremyC. So you mean (according to the sqlfiddle) the "OR i.index IS NULL " should be removed?

Comment: no I mean depending on what behaviour OP wants when the index of an item is null it should be kept or removed, my point in the fiddle was, I added an item where the index is null, do we want it to be removed from result or not? (in my fiddle it is in the result because I didn't remove the OR i.index IS NULL)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT us.id
      ,us.name
      ,it.items
FROM USER US
     LEFT JOIN ITEMS IT ON US.ID = IT.ID 
     AND (IT.index = 2 OR IT.index IS NULL);
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1274e/6)**

Comment: same answer as Jarlh except yours won't work in oracle sql since you are aliassing tables using AS, that is meant for column names

Comment: That was automatically added by auto syntax format. As you could see, it is not set in SQL Fiddle....

Comment: alright, sadly I can't edit my vote unless answer is edited, which is strange :s